# Glassfish: how can I make server use single class loader for several applications

Tags: glassfish, classloader

I have several web/ejb applications. These applications use some common libraries and should share instances of classes from those libraries.
But applications are being deployed independently thus packaging all them to EAR is not acceptable.
I suppose the problem is that each application uses separate class loader.
How can I make AS use single class loader for a set of applications?

Different applications depend on different libraries so I need a way that will not share library for all applications on the domain but only for some exact applications.

When I placed common jar to **%domain%/lib** - all works. But that jar is shared between all applications on the domain.
When I tried to place common jar to **%domain%/lib/applibs** and specified **--libraries** attribute on deploying I got exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: a.FirstDao cannot be cast to a.FirstDao
```

Here http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4336/6nfqd2b1t/index.html I read:

> If multiple applications or modules
>   refer to the same libraries, classes
>   in those libraries are automatically
>   shared. This can reduce the memory
>   footprint and allow sharing of static
>   information.

Does it mean that classes should be able to be casted ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the domain/lib directory.  Although it makes your libraries available to all applications running on that domain, does it really matter if the other apps are not using those libs?

If you want to eliminate that exposure, you are more looking at delivering your group of applications as an individual EAR to isolate library usage to just those applications.